# Color of the line marker in DropMode.INSERT_ROW

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable where the rows can be moved with drag&drop. I'm using DropMode.INSERT_ROW for this (so the drop location is marked with a horizontal line between the rows of the table).

By default the line is gray, with black along the column the mousepointer is currently over.

How can I change the color of this line? And is it possible to not "mark" the column-bit with black?

I want to avoid making my own handler for this. Simply looking for something like setMarkerColor() or something like that, but I'm having a very hard time finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible unless you bite the bullet and write your own handler (or use some third-party handler). There is no built-in method like `setMarkerColor()`.

Java's closest options allow you to change the color of the table grid through `JTable.setGridColor()` and when to display the drop indicator through `TransferHandler.setShowDropLocation()`. Neither of these options has any effect on the line-with-black-column-indicator behavior relevant to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your only hope would possibly be in the UIDefaults for the table, depending on which look and feel you are using.

Looking in Nimbus, I would guess something like: Table.dropLineColor might be the right property to change, but I am not sure, so you might have to do some testing to find out which will work.